# Path of Twig with variable of Backbone

Tags: symfony, backbone.js, twig, underscore.js, symfony-2.1

I would like to know how was it possible to insert code from Backbone / Underscore function in twig?

Here is my problem:

```
{{path('getArticle', {"id": <%= id %>})}}
```

I need to change this variable : `<%= id %>`

This does not work because Twig Parse before the Backbone code. So I do not know how to give a variable of this type?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Symfony in the server side, along with TWIG.
In that case, you just have to send the $id variable to your TWIG template

```
public function callMyTwigAction($deskId)
{
    $id=whatIwant();
    return array('id' => $id);
}
```

and then just call in your TWIG file :

```
{{path('getArticle', {"id": id})}}
```

It looks like you are mismatching client template and server template.
A client template like [Underscore Template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) (or rather use [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)) is transforming raw web services data (JSON or XML) into HTML and is (probably) written in Javascript.

Server side template usually transforms business objects (Java/PHP classes) into HTML and uses an engine such as TWIG or Velocity.

Comment: thanks, but it's more complecated, i think, i my case. This is my complete code :

Answer (score 0):

With the more complicated architecture I would propose three things :

- simplify your architecture :) Something is perhaps wrong.
- Make a web service to get the path of a given id (but this would make the architecture even more complex)
- create an array of paths with Twig in your javascript. Thiw may be ok if there is less than 200 articles and if this page is not too often displayed.

Do you use TWIG in the server side ? What technology stack do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Use FOSJSRoutingBundle.  It generates a map of all your exposed TWIG routes, which you can then use in your Javascript.

Making the Routing component global, or inject it into your underscore template.  Then simply call it similarly to how you would do it in TWIG, but with a JS notation:

```
<a href="<%= Routing.generate('getArticle', {'id': id}) %>">Get Article <%= id %></a>
```